# Rails: error messages without brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can i display Rails error messages without brackets and quotes?

When a error message appears, it looks like:

```
["please fill out domain"]["please fill out email"]
```

How can i remove the brackets and the quotes?

**Model**

```
validates :domain,
          :presence => { :message => 'please fill out domain'},
          :uniqueness => { :message => 'domain already registered', :case_sensitive => true }
validates :email,
          :presence => { :message => 'please fill out email'},
          :uniqueness => { :message => 'email already registered', :case_sensitive => true }
```

**Controller**

I'm specify the url of the template (see `format.html`) cause i'm using a different controller

```
def create

  respond_to do |format|
    # save form data
    @login = Login.new(params[:login])

    # if validation fails, throw error messages
    if !@login.save
      flash[:error] = @login.errors.to_a if @login.invalid?
    end

    # render landingpage
    format.html { render :template => 'landingpage/index' }
    format.js { render :action => 'create' }

  end

end
```

**create.js.erb**

```
<% if @login.errors.any? %>
  // error

  var error_string = "";
  <% @login.errors.values.each do |msg| %>
    error_string += "<%= msg %>";
  <% end %>

  $("#flash_messages").html(error_string);

<% else %>
 // no error
<% end %>
```

**View**

```
<div id="flash_messages"></div>
```

Comment: If you remove the `to_a` call in `@login.errors.to_a` o que acontece?

Comment: Try `@login.errors.messages.each do |msg|`

Comment: @MurifoX: Unfortunately, it doesn't change anything

Comment: @HungryCoder: Then i get: `[:domain, ["please fill out domain"]][:email, ["please fill out email"]]`

Comment: please check my answer if it works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you iterate over the  full error messages, you will already receive clean texts

In your create.js.erb, write the iteration as below:

```
@login.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
```